# Custom panel/section link styling in customizer

Tags: theme-customizer

Is it possible to change the color of a panel/section link in the WordPress customizer? Like so (example image is from a default installation but I'm talking about adding it to a custom section of course):

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to change the color and other CSS properties of a section and panel title/link. You just have to figure the CSS selector. Here's the selector pattern for section and panel.

```
#accordion-section-SECTION_ID_GOES_HERE .accordion-section-title {
    /* add CSS properties here */
}

#accordion-panel-PANEL_ID_GOES_HERE .accordion-section-title {
    /* add CSS properties here */
}
```

Say, you have a panel `example_panel` and a section `example_section` then the selectors will be like the following -

```
#accordion-section-example_section .accordion-section-title {
    background-color: tomato;
    border-left-color: tomato;
    color: #fff;
}

#accordion-panel-example_panel .accordion-section-title {
    background-color: purple;
    border-left-color: purple;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Now if you save your custom CSS in a stylesheet `customize-control.css` and want to enqueue that then you have to use [`customize_controls_enqueue_scripts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/customize_controls_enqueue_scripts).

Comment: ..and if anyone also wants to change the arrow color, then that can be done with: `#accordion-panel-example_panel .accordion-section-title::after { color:#fff; }`